How to avoid crashing android native code debugging
we have an android application that has via JNI some of our c++ multithreaded(pthreads) code running beside java android application. The problem we are facing is debugging this code. Debugging stops on breakpoints but steping over almost always crashes the application with segmentation faults. Application itself without debugging never crashes and works very well.
I am leaning towards that when debugging native code the java part crashes because the debugger stops the execution in java threads or something. I am kind of lost.
Any ideas would be helpfull.
For example the crash notification:
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x74 in tid 3010 (Thread-5), pid 2777 (ra.xxxxx)
crash_dump.cpp:415] failed to attach to thread 3010, already traced by 2866 (/data/data/com.xxxxx/lldb/bin/lldb-server)

crash_dump helper failed to exec
channel '9c25d2e com.xxxxx/com.xxxxx.activities.xxxxActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

If the device is slower crashes are more occuring.
Thank you
BR

You use Android Studio for native code debugging?

Part of the code is started in a thread via jni and runs native

SIGSEGV is segmentation fault, which is usually related to invalid memory access. Identify critical JNI methods and avoid placing breakpoints there. Instead, use logging to debug those areas. Use tools like Valgrind (for Linux) or AddressSanitizer to check for invalid memory access, data races, or other memory issues. You can also add native logging using __android_log_print() in your C/C++ code to understand the flow of execution leading up to the crash.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/debuggerd/crash_dump.cpp#109. Are you sure your native code doesn't explicitly ptrace spawned threads?
